# How to check if there aren't enough color values in an RGB ppm image

Tags: c++, arrays, whitespace, ppm

I am making a function that loads a ppm image into a 2 dimensional array, where each item in the array is a struct holding the red, green, and blue values. Among other things, the function needs to check if, given a certain height and width dimension for the image, the file has enough color values to fill the array. The unit test for this error check is failing and exiting with the error that flags non integer values.

How do I fix this? (I am attempting to check for not enough color values at the beginning of the nested for loops)

```
bool loadImage(string filename, Pixel** image, int width, int height) {
    // checks if file can open
    ifstream fin(filename);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error: failed to open input file - " << filename << endl;
        return false;
    }


    // checking if p3
    char type[3];
    fin >> type;  // should be p3
    if (((toupper(type[0]) != 'P') && (toupper(type[0]) != 'p')) || (type[1] != '3')) {
        cout << "Error: type is " << type << " instead of P3" << endl;
        return false;
    }


    // input value does not match value in file (entered width and height not same as that of image)
    int filewidth = 0;
    int fileheight = 0;
    fin >> filewidth;
    fin >> fileheight;
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Error: read non-integer value" << endl;
        cout << "1" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (filewidth != width) {
        cout << "Error: input width (" << width << ") does not match value in file (" << filewidth << ")" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if (fileheight != height) {
        cout << "Error: input height (" << height << ") does not match value in file (" << fileheight << ")" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // get max color from preamble
    int maxColor = 0;
    fin >> maxColor;
    if (maxColor != 255) {
        cout << "Error: file is not using RGB color values" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // get RGB color values

    int red=0;
    int green=0;
    int blue=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {  // switched height and width and i++ and j++ to ++i and ++j
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            if (fin.eof()) {
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> red;
            if (fin.eof()) {
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> green; 
            if (fin.eof()) {
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> blue;
            if (fin.eof() && i < (height -1) && j < (width -1)) { // reads eof and hasn't reached full span of file
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }


            // checking valid color range
            if (red < 0 || red > 255) {
                cout << "Error: invalid color value " << red << endl;
                return false;
            }
            if (green < 0 || green > 255) {
                cout << "Error: invalid color value " << green << endl;
                return false;
            }
            if (blue < 0 || blue > 255) {
                cout << "Error: invalid color value " << blue << endl;
                return false;
            }

            // non integer values check
            if (fin.fail()) {
                cout << "Error: read non-integer value" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            image[j][i].r = red;  
            image[j][i].g = green;
            image[j][i].b = blue;
        }
    }

    // too many color values
    fin >> red;
    if (!fin.eof()) {
        cout << "Error: too many color values" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: `(toupper(type[0]) != 'p')` will always be `true`. So `(toupper(type[0]) != 'P') && (toupper(type[0]) != 'p')` will test `true` for any file not beginning with `'P'`. Either `fin >> filewidth;` or `fin >> fileheight;` is failing triggering your non-integer error.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I Already thought of that and it's not that. See the "1" under the error statement for the fin.fail() that checks whether height and width aren't integers? The fin.fail() within the nested for loops that checks whether RGB values are integers used to have a "2" under the error return so I could see which was causing it. It was the 2 - the fin.fail() within the nested for loops.

Comment: Oh, why do you have `fin >> ws;`? [std::basic_istream::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will skip the whitespace between integer values. Where is `ws` declared? If it is `char` or `int` -- you have your answer. It is reading part of your RGB and you will end up short on colors for your file.

Comment: I got that from someone on the class forum saying that we needed to "put eof before reading in a color value and consuming whitespace using std::ws" to check if there aren't enough color values. So I added that as an attempt to do what she was saying. I think when there aren't enough values, the rest of the space is white space? And when my program reads those white spaces that's why it throws the error that it's read a non integer value and exited. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: The problem may be failing to check for comments in the [PPM - Format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). Comments (beginning with `'#'`) can appear anywhere before the start of the raster (the RGB values) in your `.ppm` file. So they can appear `type` and before `height` and `width`, between `height` and `width` and `maxcolor` and between `maxcolor` and the start of the raster. Without seeing your input file, that is another issue to cover. Also, while you should use a `std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>>`, how is `image` handled?

Comment: Here is a short example I put together to [Read PPM](https://paste.opensuse.org/28338965) based on the example file in [PPM - Format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) -- it allocates within the `loadppm()` function -- since I'm not sure how you are doing it --  that was a reasonable choice given you `Pixel **image` parameter (though I use a reference instead). It will ignore comments anywhere they can appear in the `.ppm` file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much I'll take a look and try it. I think though it's purely an issue with my method for checking when there aren't enough color values. My code is graded on something called mimir where my professor writes programs with very specific test cases to grade our code. I am passing 42 / 43 test cases where the only one that's failing is the one that checks if, given a file with a certain height and width in the preamble, does not have enough color values to fill in those height and width dimensions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin to clarify the above- In the assignment they tell us exactly what to take into account and comments in the ppm file weren't mentioned or shown in the examples so I don't think it's that. I think I must jus have a logic error. But I appreciate what you've done and suggested!

Comment: Sounds like you have a good handle on it. Your logic works if there is no comments. Consider a single read, e.g. `if (!(fin >> red >> green >> blue)) { /* handle error */ }` which would greatly simplify your logic and may help you narrow down the issue. (or read directly to `image[i][j].r`...) What if you have a zero or huge `height` & `width`. Worth a chat with the duck, See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a problem with how I was checking  if there weren't enough colors in the ppm image. I needed to account for the fact that I was exiting with the error that checked for non integer values whenever there weren't enough color values.

below is just the segment at the beginning of the nested for loops that I changed.

```
int red=0;
    int green=0;
    int blue=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            if (fin.eof()) {
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> red;
            if (fin.eof() && fin.fail()) { // reads eof and hasn't reached full span of file
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> green; 
            if (fin.eof() && fin.fail()) { // reads eof and hasn't reached full span of file
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }

            fin >> ws;
            fin >> blue;
            if (fin.eof() && fin.fail()) { // reads eof and hasn't reached full span of file
                cout << "Error: not enough color values" << endl;
                return false;
            }
```